# Submit new app build when previous has rejected status and appeal is still open

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

What happens if I have an app in review with solution A (rejected but an appeal is in progress for a week already) and I will send a new build with solution B to review? Does it automatically stop the appeal?
I submitted an appeal using this form: https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=appeal

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to submit a build while you have one in review unless it has a higher version number. E.g. if 3.0 is in appeal, you will be able to upload 3.1 but not another version of 3.0

Comment: Currently I can't create new app version in App Store Connect. The only way is to remove build from current 1.0 version and upload new with increased build number and submit 1.0 version again to review but I've opened appeal for previous rejected build and I don't want to stop it. I don't know whats happen after that so I'm looking for someone which had a situation like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit another binary for review on App Store Connect, your appeal is invalidated.

So in your case, if you submit solution B for a review, the appeal for A would no longer be considered by the board.